# How to fix unserialize error at offset

Tags: php, serialization, opencart

I'm getting this error does anyone know how to fix it?

```
 Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 65533 of 65535 bytes in /home/corrchil/public_html/index.php on line 74
```

It is now on the top of every page and started to be seen on the pages after we installed a plugin, we have since removed the plugin and everything that could have been edited.

https://www.corrchilled.co.uk/alpine-prague-68-super-slim-remote-multideck.html

Comment: Are you using a particular framework/CMS/system or is this custom PHP code?

Comment: @Turnerj We're using Opencart 1.5.5.1

Comment: What was the plugin and where can we find its code?

Comment: When I get those errors it normally means I have somehow corrupted my serialized string...

Comment: The posted link no longer presents the issue and there was no hardcoded string in the question.  This issue cannot be replicated and therefore cannot be confidently solved.  Voting as Off-topic: Why isn't my code working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try base64_encode() after you serialize your datas:

```
$serialized = base64_encode(serialize($datas)));
```

then:

```
$unserialized = unserialize(base64_decode($serialized));
```